# iOS notifications from web app

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, notifications

I'm writting an app in Backbone and Marrionette, and I would like to show notifications on Apple's machines. Can I do this without developing application on iOS? Some JS libraries which can to push notifications if person use Apple phone or tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about native push notifications then no. (unless you're wrapping your app in PhoneGap)

If you're talking about push notifications while the person is on the browser then yes. 
I've usually rolled my own notifications using either websockets, or signalr in the .NET world, to tell the client that something has happened. There are also a couple services like [pusher](http://pusher.com/) that can help you get something up a little faster if you don't feel like making your own implementation

Comment: So to be precised. If I want to push notification from browser (for example by JS straight to OS) it will not work. But If I use external service (by JS to the service and then to OS) It will work. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. If I can assume what your goal is here you want the iOS device to show a notification like when you receive a new email from Gmail or an update from Facebook. This will not be possible unless you write a native application that can accept your notification. a service like pusher is only making it easier for different platforms to accept your message without you having to write your own back end to support it.

Answer (score 0):

No, on iOS push notification are only support by apps.

This is clearly state in the documentation, [Notification Programming Guide for Websites](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) :

> Note: This document pertains to OS X only. Notifications for websites do not appear on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to implement web side to use **Push Notification**. It have server side implementation.